# Javascript Mongodb does not update when 2 users update the same document, only 1 of them can update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb, next.js

In my NextJS application, I have a basic Mongodb connection like this

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = "serverurl";
const ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectId;

export async function addComment(reqBody) {

  const client = new MongoClient(url);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db();

    result = await db
      .collection("posts")
      .updateOne(
        { _id: new ObjectID(reqBody.ID) },
        { $set: { postComments: reqBody.comments } }
      );

    await client.close();
```

The problem is, if **2 user updates** the document about **same time**, **only one of them update applies**. By mean of "update", I'm just adding strings to an array in the collection. I've checked on the internet but all of the answers says that Mongodb internally handles concurrent updates, which doesn't seem here.

I also saw that no need to close the connection, but if I don't close the connection, everytime I request to this API in the application, the connection `connect()` starts again and there will be lots of connections ends up Mongodb warning "You are close to 500 connections, restart the application." By the way I already tried this too, I didn't close the connection, still if more than 1 people updates at the same time, only 1 can update.

How can I handle concurrent requests so they will be in que and all updates will eventually apply?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not applying both updates where the second one overwrites the first? Should you be `$push`ing (or `$addToSet`ting) the new comments instead of rewriting the whole array (with potentially outdated info from the client)?

Comment: @user20042973 well you are right I'm actually setting a new array each time a request made, via $set, but I expect that all requests will que one after one, so they will override the latest array. Isn't this the case?

Comment: @user20042973 by the way, in another component, I do have to override the last statement. It's like I have a counter, whenever a user clicks to the button, I add 1 to the counter. So, I assume I have to use $set in there, but as I understand it doesn't returns the updated collection right? Is that the problem?

Comment: Use `$inc` for the increment